# Clear or restart async function

Tags: javascript

I have created async function in tableau extension that captures all data from ui and export it as Excel. The issue im facing is that this will only work on the first onclick trigger.

1. First Trigger : Excel Size Exported -> 100KB
2. Second Trigger : Excel Size Exported -> 200KB

Not only this will double in size, when i tried to open the excel exported with the function i created on the second trigger. it was giving me error.

Function i created with async

****i  simplied and remove my script to show only async function for better understanding*

```
    async function exportListener() {
        for (let i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
                const val = await viz.getWorkbook().activateSheetAsync(sheet[i])
                ..
                await generateExport(val, sheet[i].$0.name.trim())
        }
       ..
    }

         async function generateExport(_sheetDetails, sheetName) {
            ..
            await _sheetDetails.getWorksheets()[i].getSummaryDataAsync().then(dataTable => {
            ..
    }
```

I read up on promise function and tried implementing in such way

```
function triggerDownload(){
   let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve,myReject){
        setTimeout(() => {
            exportListener()             
        }, 2000); 
        myResolve();
        myReject();
    });


myPromise.then(
function(value) { console.log("Success")}
,function(error) { console.log("Failure on promise statement ") });
}
```

HTML Tag

```
<button onclick="triggerDownload()"> export </button>
```

One workaround i did was to reload the browser as shown in below script however this is not the ideal approach. I was wondering if there is any alternative that i could clear/kill/restart async/await function so that i could retrigger exportListener function without doubling its size and without refreshing the browser

```
...
setTimeout(() => {
                exportListener()     
                location.reload()        
            }, 2000); 
...
```

Comment: You could put a timestamp in the filename and delete the older ones after a set number of days, for example.. why do you add to the same file instead of overwriting it?

Comment: its not overwriting the same file after it has been exported . e.g 1st ) exported file : test.xls  , second exported file is test(1).xls

Comment: But the error you found is that it has twice the size if onclick triggers twice? So why not create a new file each time onclick is called?

Comment: even if we create a new file, we need to clear/restart async function. i have tried your approach but its still having the same result

Comment: Well the async calls are already out, you cannot cancel them. You will have to send an identifier or something so the backend knows to create a new file instead of adding to the current one.